# How does Depth First Search (Recursive) work once it reaches the leaf node?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, search, binary-search-tree, depth-first-search

Currently learning about DFS and just have a few questions about the mechanics of how it works.

Repl link below due to the lengthy nature of the code:

https://repl.it/@Stylebender/DFS-Recursive

1. Is the base case of the traverseInOrder function just 'return list'?
2. As you can see from Line 45 and when the code is run (console logging the route in which the nodes are traversed), I understand that JS recursively goes down from 9 => 4 => 1 as there is still a leftward node.

My question is why and how does it traverse from Node 1 to Node 6? In other words, how is the traverseinOrder function able to receive Node 6 as an argument after 1?

Answer (score 0):

I copy the lines 39 to 55 to make the answer understandable:

```
DFTInOrder(){
   return traverseInOrder(this.root, []);
 } 
}

//Note, base case occurs where the node within the function no longer has any children.
function traverseInOrder(node, list){
 console.log(node.value);
 if(node.left) {
   traverseInOrder(node.left, list);
 }
 list.push(node.value);
 if(node.right) {
   traverseInOrder(node.right, list);
 }
 return list;
}
```

1. No, `traverseInOrder` updates the `list` parameter and then returns it. As you see at line 39, the initial list is empty. Then, for each call of `traverseInOrder`, `node.value` is added to the list after the nodes of the left branch are traversed and before the nodes of the right branch are traversed. The base case (when left and right are empty) is:

> add `node.value` to the current `list` **and then** return this `list`.

2. There is a pitfall here, since you traverse the nodes using an *in-ordering*, but you log them using a *pre-ordering*. Look at what happens when you call `traverseInOrder` with arguments: `Node(4)` and `list=[]`:

```
    function traverseInOrder(node, list){
      console.log(node.value); // log 4
      if(node.left) { // 1
        traverseInOrder(node.left, list); 
        // log 1
        // add 1 to the list (since 1.left and 1.right are null)
      }
      list.push(node.value); // add 4 to the list
      if(node.right) { // 6
        traverseInOrder(node.right, list); 
        // log 6
        // add 6 to the list (since 6.left and 6.right are null)
      }
      return list;
    }
```

Hence the traverse order: `1, 4, 6`. But you log the nodes  `4, 1, 6`.